# Django http cookies: set-cookie vs. cookies

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am trying to figure out how Django is [setting a cookie](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/http/response.py#L210). Is it returning it as a set-cookie header or including the cookies in the response payload object? See info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html#urls-cookies).

Answer (score 0):

I logged a response and could see that cookies are returned in the `set-cookie` header.